# How do I remove the blue box around editable elements upon editing?

Tags: css, html

We can make HTML elements editable by using the `contentEditable="true"` attribute:

```
<div contentEditable="true">
    This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxmr6gzg/)

How can I make the blue box surrounding the element go away when the user edits the content?

I've tried using the `:active` and `:hover` pseudo-classes (along with `border: none`) to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not border but [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) which you see on focus. You can try this:

```css
div[contentEditable] {
    outline: none;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bxmr6gzg/1/